# Running msbuild via cmake inside powershell

Tags: powershell, cmake

I have a CMake project that generates a Visual Studio solution that builds with MSBuild.

The command I am using to build the project is:

```
cmake --build Debug -- -v:diag
```

using the `--` option causes the `-v:diag` option to be passed to MSBuild.

When run from a command prompt, everything is fine.

However, when run from within a powershell prompt, it breaks:

```
PS C:\proj> cmake --build Debug --verbose -- -v:diag
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

MSBUILD : error MSB1016: Specify the verbosity level.
Switch: -v:

For switch syntax, type "MSBuild -help"
```

Seems powershell is doing something to parse the arguments around the colon `:`.

How can I cause powershell to pass the argument string as-is to cmake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you've hit a bug in PowerShell's parameter binder, present up to at least PowerShell 7.2.4:

`-v:diag` is unexpectedly passed as *two* arguments, `-v:` and `diag`, *if `--` comes beforehand* in calls to external programs - see [GitHub issue #17399](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17399).

As a workaround, *quote* the argument:

```sh
cmake --build Debug --verbose -- '-v:diag'
```

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Brad; my pleasure.